# How to implement Android Application with Facebook authentication and backend server

Tags: android, authentication, facebook-graph-api, backend

I am working on the mobile application for android which is written in Android Studio in Java language.  I would like to implement Facebook authentication firstly and then Google and I will see which else.

A lot of backout action will be carry out by backend server. I spent a lot of time to figure out the solution but I didn’t find the response which straight explant me how should I proceed with facebook Authentication and tokens.
I have already implemented facebook API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android ) in my mobile application. I can get access token and so on. After that I stuck and could you tell me is there any way to connect this access token which I have got on my phone which backend server? Or should start everything from the beginning and Manually Build a Login Flow?

Second question. Could you tell me if what is correct and the easiest way to connect Mobile App, Backend Server and Facebook authentication? 
I would like to have something like that I know that comparing access token is not acceptable but can you tell me how to do it?

[Facebook API with application server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8w5O.png)

Comment: You send your token from the client to the server, and then you make an API request from there to debug it, to verify that token is genuine. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security#tokenhijacking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a Login flow as below

1. Send token-to-inspect(access token), user facebookID  and remaining user data to your server
2. On server side check the response for access_token from the **Step 1**

[https://graph.facebook.com/debug_token?input_token={token-to-inspect}&access_token={app_id}|{app_secret}](https://graph.facebook.com/debug_token?input_token=%7Btoken-to-inspect%7D&access_token=%7Bapp_id%7D%7C%7Bapp_secret%7D)

Note that a sign "|" in the above URL isn't used as OR but as a separator and must be there after filling the other fields.

Also don't send app_id, app_secret from the app, keep them on the server side only.

3. If in response you get the same user_id, is_valid, application then it is a valid user else not.
4. After verifying in **Step 3** give user your own auth_token for accessing app resources

Also, check out Firebase Authentication and Firebase ADMIN to make this flow safe/secure and developer friendly.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you a lot. I have seen this page but I was not sure how to use it. Your answer brighten my view for this case, many thanks.